# Accessing web forms from Masterpage navigation menu

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a web application in Asp.net and c# where I have a master page in which there is a Left Side Navigation menu containing the links to different web forms. But these web forms are in different locations. For example `ClientDetails.aspx` and `UserDetails.aspx` are present at the root and `AdminHome.aspx` is present in the `Admin` folder where my master page resides.

So when I click on Client on Navigation menu, it opens nicely but from this place when I click on Admin Home in the nav to redirect back to Admin home page, it gives an error as

```
The resource cannot be found.
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: Please don't add a C tag to a question that has nothing to do with C.

Comment: @schaiba  Man, it was added by mistake, I didn't add it intentionally bcoz I also have nothing to do with C in this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When specifying the URL for you pages, it should be in is format with the tilda as shown below:

```
<a href="~/ClientDetails.aspx">Client Details</a>

<a href="~/UserDetails.aspx">User Details</a>

<a href="~/Admin/AdminHome.aspx">Admin Home</a>
```

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you. I appreciate the support. Thanks!

Comment: I did Mr. Jason, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the URL those menu items are redirecting to. Ensure that the relative path for the forms is correct based on current forms location. Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx) page to understand how paths work.